# Allocating a value to a pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to give a value to a pointer.
this code works fine

```
int i =5;   
int *ptr ;   
ptr = &i;   
printf(" %d\n",*ptr);
```

but this code shows an error

```
int i =5;   
int *ptr ;   
*ptr = 5;   
printf(" %d\n",*ptr);
```

can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Why did you decide not to tell us what the error was?

Comment: It is showing a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

`int *ptr` gets initialized to a random location, which possibly points to invalid memory, and you try to write 5 to that location.

Comment: So how can i do it without using any other variable( "i" in code)?

Comment: Well, you can't. If you want to write to a location by dereferencing (i.e. doing `*ptr`) the pointer, the pointer needs to point to a valid location, and to get a valid location you have to allocate a variable first (e.g. `int i = 5;`). An alternative would be to use dynamic memory, but I don't think that's what you need. I think I need to know why you want to do that (instead of using a regular variable) to tell you how you can do what you want to do :)

Answer (score 2):

When you declare `int *ptr`, you're creating a variable called `ptr` which can hold the address of an `int`.  When you dereference it in `*ptr = 5`, you're saying "store 5 in the address that `ptr` points to" - but as `ptr` is uninitialised, where it points to is undefined.  So you're invoking undefined behaviour.

An `int *` does not store an `int`, but just an address that points to one.  There still has to be a real `int` *at* that address.

If you want to allocate an `int` that exists outside of the local scope, you can use `malloc`.  A simple conversion of your example without error checking:

```
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
*ptr = 5;
printf(" %d\n",*ptr);
```

If you do use `malloc`, just remember to `free` the allocated memory when you're finished:

```
free(ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second version assigns 5 to the memory pointed to by `ptr`, but you haven't yet initialized `ptr` to point to a known location.

So it writes the value to the memory at whatever address happens to be in `ptr`, which is whatever was in memory where `ptr` was declared.

Answer (score 0):

You can't deterrence a pointer that doesn't point to somewhere you own.

```
int* ptr;
```

That allocates space for the pointer, but it doesn't allocate space for the chunk the pointer points to.

Also, since it's not initialized, ptr has an indeterminate value. This means that not only does it likely point to something you don't own, it also would be rather difficult to check if it's a valid pointer. It's usually a good idea to initialize pointers to either NULL (or nullptr if available) or an actual location (like you did in the first example).